# MYSQL show results if column is in & if another colum is like

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a MYSQL query to only display rows that match 2 WHERE statments.

e.g.

```
$result=mysql_query("
  SELECT *
  FROM tablename
  WHERE
    (column1 IN $phpimplodestring1) OR
    (column2 LIKE $phpimplodestring2)
  GROUP BY column2
  ORDER BY id /* another column */
  DESC LIMIT 5
")
```

Everything i've searched for hasn't worked so far, and after weeks of testing, not result.
I've tried using mysqli, but it doesn't appear to be working at all when using it.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: What's wrong with `AND` ?

Comment: I suppose you must use AND. Pay attention to use GROUP BY column2 with a * select field list (not good)

Comment: @AlmaDo, for some reason, when i first tried that on some older versions, it ignored one of them, rewrote it and used AND and it worked! :) thanks for your help!

Comment: So nice to know that I have the power to make things work.

Comment: This use of GROUP BY has its proponents. Personally, I think it's symptomatic of someone who doesn't really know what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the WHERE clause.
Pay attention to your aggregation, you is grouping by column2 but is declaring * in the select. The select clause must match the aggregation clause and you is not even declaring a aggregation function.

The examples below can work (depends on what do you want)

```
SELECT column2, count(*) as QTD
  FROM tablename
  WHERE
    (column1 IN $phpimplodestring1) OR
    (column2 LIKE $phpimplodestring2)
  GROUP BY column2
  ORDER BY id /* another column */
  DESC LIMIT 5


SELECT *
  FROM tablename
  WHERE
    (column1 IN $phpimplodestring1) OR
    (column2 LIKE $phpimplodestring2)
  ORDER BY id /* another column */
  DESC LIMIT 5


SELECT column2, sum(anotherColumn)
  FROM tablename
  WHERE
    (column1 IN $phpimplodestring1) OR
    (column2 LIKE $phpimplodestring2)
  GROUP BY column2
  ORDER BY id /* another column */
  DESC LIMIT 5


SELECT distinct *
  FROM tablename
  WHERE
    (column1 IN $phpimplodestring1) OR
    (column2 LIKE $phpimplodestring2)
  ORDER BY id /* another column */
  DESC LIMIT 5
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks Jean, I managed to get what i needed working, by using AND instead of OR... not sure why it wasn't working earlier... but rewriting code seems to often work wonders! :)

I'll try some of your options as well, looks like they mite speed it up a bit. Thanks again

Comment: Nice, in that case post your working code and mark it as the answer

Comment: Not enough rep to answer it yet, but here it is:
Solved it, so now it only shows rows that have column1 in the list AND also column2 are like one of the items in the list. (which is a php implode to do mutiple LIKE '' OR)
'$result=mysql_query("
      SELECT *
      FROM tablename
      WHERE
        (column1 IN $phpimplodestring1) AND
        (column2 LIKE $phpimplodestring2)
      GROUP BY column2
      ORDER BY id /* another column */
      DESC LIMIT 5
    ")
'

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `admin_user` WHERE `user_name` IN ('arpit','niraj') OR `admin_name` LIKE 'arpit' GROUP BY `admin_name` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";

Here i took 
tablename = `admin_user` 
column1 = `admin_user`   & 
column2  = `admin_user`

i have tried this and i got result in Query Window with given order..